# There is an attribute error when i was going to train my model which is directoryiterator object has no attribute shape?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I try to run this code but still stuck with this error when I was going to train my model and had raised this error : AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'shape'

if anyone had this error and fix it, please, let me know how you fixed it.

Thank you
(i am using pycharm)

```
     from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
     import tensorflow as tf
     from pil import Image

     classifier = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", 
     input_shape= (64,64, 3),activation='relu'))
     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))


     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same" , 
     activation="relu"))
     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))


     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())


     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
     classifier.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))


     classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     classifier.summary()


     from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

     train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                       shear_range=0.2,
                                       zoom_range=0.2,
                                       horizontal_flip=True)

     test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                      shear_range=0.2,
                                      zoom_range=0.2,
                                      horizontal_flip=True)

     training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                     target_size=(64, 64),
                                                     batch_size=32,
                                                     class_mode='binary')

     test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                                target_size=(64, 64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='binary')

     classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                             steps_per_epoch=8000,
                             epochs=25,
                             validation_data=test_set,
                             validation_steps=2000)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1297, in fit_generator
        steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
      File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 144, in model_iteration
        shuffle=shuffle)
      File "C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 477, in  
 convert_to_generator_like
        num_samples = int(nest.flatten(data)[0].shape[0])
    AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: you are mixing tf.keras and keras in your imports

Comment: you can see my new code below please check it and tell me where I made mistake